# Offline map using cloudmade

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

how can i implement offline map using cloudmade? is it possible with cloudemade? is there any sample code? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look this [discussion at the official CloudMade forum](http://support.cloudmade.com/forums/iphone-sdk/posts/104/show). There is no inbox solution, but guys have described an approach in general with some tech details.